# Audio Input to Audio Output

Tags: sound, input, output

My audio output is broken, but I also have an audio input which I don't need.

Is there any chance that I could change them so the input will be the output?

Comment: This question might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/27804/using-microphone-input-port-as-headphone-output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using microphone input port as headphone output](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27804/using-microphone-input-port-as-headphone-output)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change which audio jacks are used for input and output?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225017/how-do-i-change-which-audio-jacks-are-used-for-input-and-output)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. Look here [How do I change which audio jacks are used for input and output?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225017/how-do-i-change-which-audio-jacks-are-used-for-input-and-output) .

Note: I'm also from Germany :D