# pavucontrol, switch from back port to front port

Tags: 16.04, sound, xubuntu, pulseaudio, headphones

I recently reinstalled xubuntu 16.04 and am getting some weird behavior with pavucontrol. I have speakers plugged in the front jack of my computer and headphones in the back jack. The speakers work fine, the headphones are 'unplugged' according to pavucontrol. Switching to headphones mutes the speakers and there is no sound from headphones. Unplugging speakers results in headphones being 'plugged in' and working. Disabling auto-mute in alsamixer results in both playing sound when speakers are selected, but only headphones play sound when headphones are selected. I'd like it to switch cleanly between the two, like it did before i reinstalled. Any ideas?

Comment: Haven't done myself but you may try with [hdajackretask](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27804/using-microphone-input-port-as-headphone-output).

Comment: I just tried retasking the two jacks. If I swap the two jacks, the behavior stays the same but instead of favoring the speakers it favors my headphones. It favors whatever pavucontrol calls 'Headphones' and mutes/unplugs 'Line Out'.